# The way to change DOM before the DOM is loaded completely

Tags: javascript, dom

I know Some programs (like grease monkey) can modify DOM just after the DOM is loaded completely.

But Is it possible during the DOM is loading? or before loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe already answered here :

[Chrome Extension : Modify DOM before loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778637/chrome-extension-modify-dom-before-loading) 
[Is it ok to manipulate dom before ready state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222849/is-it-ok-to-manipulate-dom-before-ready-state) 
[Possible to modify DOM during/before initial DOM parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575185/possible-to-modify-dom-during-before-initial-dom-parsing)

Comment: Should be a comment if you only want to post some links :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Check out this example:

```
<div id="t">Some text</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('t').textContent = "Other text";
</script>
<div>Yay!</div>
```

The script part will modify the DOM even though the "Yay!" div hasn't loaded. It can only do that because the `<div id="t">` is *already* loaded, though.

This is the extent of how much you can do.

If you want to insert something while the DOM is loading, you can use `document.write` (this is the trick that most ads providers use to add the script tag wherever their snippet is added).

Comment: Thanks Margaine. yes.. above example works. But, Can something insert code(above script) during the DOM is loading?

Comment: I mean.. can any OTHER PROGRAMS change browser DOM during A BROWSER DOM is loading

Comment: @kwangbul oh, then look at Jean-Michel Garcia's first link, it's exactly what you want (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778637/chrome-extension-modify-dom-before-loading).